# Update data in yaml files in Gitlab

Tags: git, yaml

We have recently moved to Gitlab for CI/CD. In our setup our applications get their properties from yaml file i.e.

appl123 has 4 property files appl123-dev.yaml, appl123-sit.yaml, appl123-uat.yaml, appl123-prod.yaml.

Once a year we update an important database and build a server with the new version of the database. To test the new version we need to update the properties to point to the new server i.e.

Previous version: jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz-db-acmeDDD-ac1.its.mycomp.org:1521/ACME

needs to be updated to

jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz-db-acmeMMM-at1.its.mycomp.org:1521/ACME

At the moment we are updating this URL by going into each applications property yaml file, opening the file in edit-mode, updating the to the new URL and saving the update.

This is quite a long task as we have 58 applications and most yaml files have a minimum of two updates that are required to be made and saved.

Can we use a script to perform this update?

Kind regards
Chris